# Rabbit amqp connection takes too long time

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqp

I've got very strange thing. Connection to my rabbit server takes 0.6 - 3 seconds ...

AMQPConnection::connect() works really long time. At my dev and stage machines everything is ok, but on production under slightly highload (publish ~10 messages\second) i've got connections time trouble...

How and where can i start my research about it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some more details could come in handy with this one: how are the connections different in production (ssl connection? DNS setup? Where is the broker hosted in each environment?) There's just too many variables in play that could explain the slow connection, making it impossible to tell you what to do to fix the problem. Something made even harder by the fact that we don't even know _how_ you're connecting (some code would be useful, as would knowing what PHP version, lib/extension, RabbitMQ version, ... you're using

Comment: Do you have enough free open socket descriptors on production? Can you show plz `sudo rabbitmqctl status | grep -A 4 file_descriptors`. About small [rabbit tuning](http://jeka.by/post/1075/rabbitmq-tuning/)

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem like RabbitMQ version, OS, platform, network parameters, php and php-amqp versions and so on. Normally, there are [How to report a problem](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp#how-to-report-a-problem) section in php-amqp readme. You may want also try to look into RabbitMQ logs and configuration, broker may apply flow control when it out of resources or so. And 10 msg/sec is not a load for RabbitMQ that you normally should worry about performance.